# average counter speed in javascript

Tags: javascript, counter, average

I have a value that counts upwards at an irregular speed. This speed can vary between 3 clicks/second and 0.2 clicks/second.

I need to display the current average count speed based on the last 5 seconds.

I have no problems in getting the overall average,  or the average over the last 5 seconds, but that would update itself every 5 seconds. What i need is to have this value constantly updating (like every 0.2 seconds) and beeing recalculated constantly. Does somebody have an idea on how this could be achived?

---

Counter is the value that is increasing at random speed.

```
window.onload = function(){
            window.setInterval(average(), 500);
                }   

        var queue = [];
        var times = [];
        var ts;
        var maxage = 3000;

        function average()
        {
        // add to queue
        ts = new Date().getTime();
        queue.push(counter);
        times.push(ts);
        if(times[0] - ts > maxage) {
           queue.shift();
           times.shift();
        }

        // read from queue
        ts = new Date().getTime();
        while(times[0] - ts > maxage) {
           queue.shift();
           times.shift();
        }
        var result;
        result = (counter - queue[0])/3;
        //g.refresh(result);
        document.getElementById('res').innerHTML =("<font size='150'>speed " + queue[0] + "</font>");
        window.setInterval(average(), 500);
        }
```

Comment: you should use [setInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.setInterval).

Comment: You should implement a queue

Comment: thanks, that is probably the only part i knew.. :) what i dont know is how to calculate the average based on the last 5 seconds from "now".. if you get what i mean..

Comment: @MajidFouladpour thanks, what do you mean? can you make an example please?

Comment: Show your current code.

Comment: there is no current code as i dont know where to start...

Comment: Couple of problems. Firstly, where do you get `counter` from?

Comment: counter is a global variable that contains the number of the counter itself.. its simply increasing.. counter is correct as i am properly displaying it on the page.

Comment: It's simply increasing? Where?

Comment: yes its simply increasing.. its connected to the IO of a raspberry and on each keypress it increases. the fster i press the button the faster it increases.

Answer (score 0):

Ordinary (length limited queue):

```
var queue = [];

// add to queue
queue.push(val);
if(queue.length > maxlen) queue.shift;

// read from queue
val = queue[0];
```

Age-limited queue:

```
var queue = [];
var times = [];
var ts;

// add to queue
ts = new Date().getTime();
queue.push(val);
times.push(ts);
if(times[0] - ts > maxage) {
   queue.shift();
   times.shift();
}

// read from queue
ts = new Date().getTime();
while(times[0] - ts > maxage) {
   queue.shift();
   times.shift();
}
val = queue[0];
```

Comment: thanks! if i get it right: i must define maxage as 5, val is the value i stored 5 seconds ago, and compared with the current value i can get the average? is that right?

Comment: For 5 seconds you should use 5000, because `getTime()` returns current timestamp down to miliseconds.

Comment: ok thanks, and also, the add queue and reaad from queue has to go inside a interval, right?

Comment: That's right. Those as well as calculating the average and updating the display.

Comment: Ok, now you have some code, add it to your question so I can help.

Comment: getting this error: `Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded `